# Trying to find the duplicates of a sum of a list

Tags: python

I am attempting to find the first set of duplicates in a list which is the sum of another list (should take a list such as [0,+1,+2,+1,-5,+1,+2] and return 0, because the sum of the list progressively [0,1,3,4,-1,0,2] has its first duplicate at 0). However, it seems to be returning wrong answers no matter what I do. Here's my code:

```
sourceList = [+11,+16,+2,-16,-6,+13,-6,-8,-17,+15,-11,-14,+17,-9,+4,+1,-15,-17,-8,+16,+6,-11,-15,-2,+3,-6,-2,-4,-2,-18,-6,-2,+18,-4,+7,+15,-11,+8,-4,-17,-19,-15,-17,-7,+12,-2,-5,-13,-4,-13,-18,+16,+12,+10,+14,-19,+13,+10,+8,-10,+3,-16,-7,-9,-19,-15,-19,+2,+7,-1,+7,+1,-20,-5,-10,+14,+10,+5,+13,+10,+15,+3,-16,-17,+19,+15,+2,+14,-11,+3,-11,-17,-8,+16,-13,-1,+16,+1,+12,-5,+20,+16,+10,-9,-8,+15,-4,+3,+5,+7,+1,-2,+19,+14,-5,-10,-4,+3,+18,-15,+17,-7,+10,-8,-10,+4,+10,+12,+11,-4,-4,-8,+11,+16,-4,+14,+2,+3,-16,+19,-9,+5,+17,+19,-17,-4,+13,+15,-6,+20,+12,+15,-17,+13,-7,-14,+11,+12,-10,+16,-10,+8,+11,-8,+16,+5,+3,-4,+15,-16,+4,+2,+5,+8,+12,+7,+8,+4,+19,-14,+2,+8,+12,-14,+19,+15,-14,-17,-5,+7,-20,-5,-4,+14,-21,+4,-8,-7,+14,-18,-7,-18,-13,-19,-8,+16,+3,-8,+14,+10,+9,+18,-15,+14,-1,+18,+15,+17,+11,+16,-11,+7,-13,-14,-6,-11,+13,-12,-2,+9,-12,+10,-18,-6,-8,+9,+3,+6,+11,+15,+15,+5,+19,+15,+8,-12,-17,-8,+19,+2,+9,+2,+6,-10,-22,-9,+19,-5,-4,+3,+14,-1,-20,+15,+17,-1,+19,-8,+11,-13,+17,+9,+9,+18,+7,-8,+11,+16,+9,-1,+15,+19,-25,+1,-6,+8,-4,+13,-23,+15,+3,-14,+1,+25,+51,-11,+5,+5,-13,+17,+13,+16,+17,+17,+18,+16,+16,-5,-20,-19,+15,-14,-15,-6,+9,-1,-5,-13,-24,+13,-18,-29,+3,+10,-14,+29,-21,+11,+13,+24,+23,-17,+19,-1,-7,-5,+20,+5,-11,+3,-20,-13,+5,-12,-8,+4,-23,-31,+18,-50,-27,-16,+15,-21,-26,-11,-46,-11,-12,-5,-1,-6,+3,+19,+7,+33,+9,+11,+14,+32,+36,+15,-92,+22,-19,-18,-8,-24,+28,-72,+15,-19,-34,-4,-11,-4,+17,+14,-26,-23,-18,-10,-1,+39,-5,+19,+16,+26,-25,-40,-11,+19,-11,+1,+7,-55,-21,+73,+503,+843,+54936,+14,-12,+13,-7,-11,+8,+11,+11,+7,+13,+12,+9,+12,+1,+7,-19,-3,-5,-1,-20,+12,+11,-10,-8,-6,+17,+19,+1,+10,-19,+4,+19,+6,+4,+3,+6,+4,+12,+3,+2,-9,+3,+9,-15,-10,-9,-10,+4,+19,+11,+19,+2,+5,+9,-15,+12,+5,+9,+18,-12,-4,+7,+13,-6,+16,+16,+12,-7,+18,+3,+15,-12,+8,-19,+3,+3,+11,-3,+17,-10,+3,-20,+6,-17,+9,+16,+18,+8,-10,-12,+13,+7,-2,-11,+10,-2,+1,-5,+10,+13,-7,+14,+17,-1,-1,+8,-4,+16,-3,+16,+17,+4,+13,-3,+8,-15,-12,+14,+16,-5,-7,+14,-12,-17,-21,-1,-16,+4,+7,-14,-12,+16,-12,-12,-8,-3,-2,-4,+16,-14,+8,+18,-8,-2,-13,+2,+17,+15,+13,+12,-4,+19,-8,-6,+5,-16,+14,-15,-18,+13,+19,-9,+23,-5,-7,+5,+12,+18,-1,+20,-7,-6,-9,-11,+6,-5,+1,+7,+14,-2,+7,+2,+14,-3,-9,+15,-2,+12,+4,-5,+8,+9,-4,+2,+13,-4,-4,-10,+4,-2,+13,-2,-12,+26,+2,+17,+20,+20,+5,-21,+12,-5,-14,+4,+12,+9,-14,-1,+10,-5,-14,-5,-17,-12,-8,+12,+11,-9,+18,+2,-12,+7,+6,-8,+6,-18,-21,-8,+1,+12,-25,-11,+4,-16,-10,+19,+12,-10,-1,-24,-7,+4,+9,-4,-19,+28,+1,+5,-8,-18,+8,-29,-26,-17,+4,-19,-8,-6,+8,+15,+36,-6,-5,-18,+6,-4,-19,-4,-11,+3,-16,-1,+2,+13,+21,-10,+32,+28,+5,+21,-36,-11,-90,-11,+17,-11,+10,+3,+2,+11,-25,-17,-9,-9,+20,-17,-19,-17,-1,+6,-2,+10,-12,+5,-9,+12,+16,+3,-18,+1,+15,-3,-8,+15,+18,+11,+5,-20,-12,+6,-3,-13,+19,-17,+19,-23,+1,-14,+20,+13,+7,+3,-21,-17,-23,-8,-18,+16,+5,+7,-6,-9,-19,-18,+17,+17,-22,+17,+15,-12,-9,-9,+14,-9,-9,+3,-8,-7,-23,+7,+22,+37,+14,+22,-20,-9,-23,+18,-8,-5,+9,-13,+25,+8,-28,+23,-39,-8,-51,-30,+3,-31,+1,+4,+172,+17,+18,-30,+18,+47,+19,-24,-14,+117,-5,+168,+14,-16,-61,+1728,+54439,-8,+15,+5,-2,-1,-12,-3,+10,+15,+10,-14,+15,-8,+11,+10,-12,+11,+12,+17,-10,-6,-19,-19,+18,-12,-3,-7,-11,-13,-10,+9,-13,+9,-15,+16,+2,+16,+13,-17,+19,+16,+16,-10,-12,-7,+5,-15,+14,+19,-12,+17,+8,-18,+17,-4,+1,+6,-13,-5,+23,-19,-8,-13,-31,-12,-3,+5,-3,+11,-1,-20,-8,+5,-2,-2,-18,+1,-19,-5,-3,+13,+15,+10,-8,-14,+16,-14,+18,-11,+6,-10,-4,+5,-15,+8,-17,-7,-12,-12,+10,+6,-12,-17,+1,+8,+17,+17,-11,+19,-18,+1,-14,-2,-15,-6,-1,-16,+1,-3,+6,-18,+1,-17,+8,+19,+18,-5,+12,+6,-15,+19,-8,-16,+18,+15,-6,+1,-17,-10,-4,-112437]
sumList = []
histList = []

for x in sourceList:
  print(str(sumList) + " is list a")
  print(str(histList) + " is list b")
  print(str(sum(sumList)) + " is the sum of list a") 
  if sum(sumList) in histList:
    print(str(sum(sumList)) + " is the answer!")
    break
  else:
    histList.append(sum(sumList))
  sumList.append(sourceList[x])
```

Comment: Prepending `+` has no effect on your code.

Comment: When I run your code, the final line prints "0 is the answer!". Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're doing, it seems like `sumList` is the "current" list (that is, the portion of `sourceList` that you've iterated over). If so, you need to append `x` (and not `sourceList[x]` as `x` is not the index but the number in `sourceList`). Next, you need to append `x` to `sumList` *before* you check `histList`:

```
sourceList = [0,+1,+2,+1,-5,+1,+2]
sumList = []
histList = []

for x in sourceList:
    sumList.append(x)
    print(sumList, histList)
    if sum(sumList) in histList:
        print(str(sum(sumList)) + " is the answer!")
        break
    histList.append(sum(sumList))
```

**Output**

```
[0] []
[0, 1] [0]
[0, 1, 2] [0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 1] [0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 1, -5] [0, 1, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 1, -5, 1] [0, 1, 3, 4, -1]
0 is the answer!
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to build the list of accumulated sums for each position in the list.  We'll add each to a `set` as we go, checking if it already exists:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def get_dupe(sourcelist):
    exists = set()
    for val in accumulate(sourcelist):
        if val in exists:
            return val
        exists.add(val)
    return None

get_dupe([0,+1,+2,+1,-5,+1,+2])
# 0
```

Your `sourcelist` will return `None`, because there are no repeated values in the accumulated sums.  `Counter(accumulate(sourcelist)).most_common(1)` has a count of `1`.